# PHP Exception: multi-operators

Tags: php, exception, if-statement, comparison-operators

I tried take user-level from my database, and check what the level of the user. When I try do this:

```
include "../web/config.php";
            $adminTrueQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$admin_username' AND `Password` = '$admin_password' LIMIT 1;");
            $adminLevel = mysql_fetch_array($adminTrueQuery);
            $adminLevel = $adminLevel['Level'];
            if($adminLevel !== "c" || "b") {
                throw new Exception ("You don't admin {$adminLevel}"); // return
            }
```

I get an error. And

```
$adminLevel = "c";
```

What the problem?

Answer (score 4):

That's not how multiple comparisons work in PHP. You need to check both values against your original value:

```
if($adminLevel !== "c" && $adminLevel !== "b") {
```

Or, if you have a lot of values to check, use `in_array()`:

```
if(!in_array($adminLevel, ['b','c'])) {
```

`$adminLevel = "c";` won't work because `=` is an assignment operator and not a comparison operator. That will always return true if the value you are trying to compare type juggles to a truthy value (which your values do).

Comment: Yes it does. Try again. Copy and paste if you have to.

Comment: maybe you mean `if($adminLevel !== "c" && $adminLevel !== "b") {`?

Comment: @AndreaGhidini you wrote your comment as I made my edit

Comment: @JohnConde About your array, `in_array()` function can't pick values some ['b', 'c'].. 
It's work only with `array()` or var that included `array('b', 'c')`.
Thanks for experienced help :)

Comment: @AndreaGhidini I was a little confused ;) thank you!